# Is there a general ASP.NET MVC helper for generating links?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I know of the ASP.NET MVC ActionLink helper for generating links to the application's actions, and find it very useful. However, I haven't been able to find a corresponding helper for generating links based on absolute URLS (i.e., to external resources). Is there a helper for this purpose?

**Edit**:
To make my question absolutely clear, I'm (obviously) not looking for a way to generate the URL part, in the way that ActionLink generates action URLs. I'm just interested in safe and easy hyperlink generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't. But you can write your own helper for that if you want the view to look nice with the consistent Helper formatting.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll roll my own. Seems to me it should be built into ASP.NET MVC though, as in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a helper for this, the helper for your action links is so that your routing works and you get nice urls. You need to know the external urls so there is no real shortcut other than putting them in config.

Comment: I understand completely that the routing aspect of ActionLink is irrelevant in this case, I'm just looking for a safer shortcut to writing <a> markup yourself, especially when the URL itself and the tag body may be dynamic. For instance, ActionLink will automatically encode special characters, such as '&' in the text. Therefore, ActionLink has functionality that is relevant outside of routing. The equivalent in Rails would be the link_to helper.

Comment: I konw what you mean about dynamic urls, but unless you know how the dynamic url at the other end is formed, you would only be guessing, so you can't really write a method for generating the link. If you need to change them or have them in a more convenient place you could add keys to your config file and read from there or if they change very often read them from a database. All of this isn't especially safer, it will just make your markup nicer, see Bumble Bee's answer for some ideas :)

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. Generating the link should be a deterministic enough task: Generate an <a> tag with encoded href and body? It's just convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an `<a>` tag when you have absolute url?

Answer (score 0):

No, Url.Action for example is the one used to generate Urls from routes which are registered in `Global.asax.cs` but since you said external and absolute how come will there be a Generator for them?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, since there is no special routing information in an absolute URL that is beneficial to use a helper to generate. You can simply use standard HTML markup - which, frankly, is far clearer to read and more customisable than helper markup. However, if you *really* would prefer to use a helper then [you can always make your own](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).

Comment: ActionLink does more than just route, it also handles encoding of the link body (i.e., translate '&' for instance). I'd like the same convenience with general links.

Comment: If it is URL encoding you require then this can be achieved via a simple method call to `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` (ideally as part of your view model that you pass to your display view) and if it HTML Encoding you require then this is automatic in Razor view and easy to achieve in traditional views using <%: %> syntax.

Comment: Ah, didn't know HTML encoding was automatic in Razor, thanks.